# Varying validation drop-downs based on varying cell values

Tags: excel-2010

I am attempting to have cells in Column “U” deliver different drop-down menus based on the corresponding value in column “D”. I have created 7 named lists:

```
List_117G
List_152
List_JMET
List_XBAND
List_PACWIND
List_VORTEX
List_ROVER
```

Those lists will be called up based on 7 values in column “D”:

```
G
152
J
X
D/E
V
R
```

So far I have only been able to get this to work for the first category `G`. When I change the value of column `D` from `G` to `152` I no longer get a drop-down. Here is the formula I am using in the List function of validation.

```
=IF(D6="G",List_117G,IF(D6="152",List_152,IF(D6="J",List_JMET,IF(D6="X",List_XBAND,IF(D6="D/E",List_PACWIND,IF(D6="V",List_VORTEX,IF(D6="R",List_ROVER,)))))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you type '152' into a cell, it will be stored as a number. You can change the *format* of that number (e.g. display as currency, percentage, date, text, etc), but that `value` will always be a number unless you specifically use the `TEXT` formula to display it as text.

In an `IF` statement, if you want to compare a cell value to a number, you can't have quotes around it.

Example:

```
      A                      B
1    152                =IF(A1="152",TRUE,FALSE) <----This will return FALSE
1    152                =IF(A1=152,TRUE,FALSE) <----This will return TRUE
1    =TEXT(152,"#")   =IF(A1="152",TRUE,FALSE) <----This will return TRUE
```

Long story short, take the quotes off of the number 152 in your `IF` statement and it should work.